# Correctly sort semantic version list using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

We use Excel to export summaries/ticket lists from our bug tracker. The column I would like to sort by is the "version" column. We use semantic versioning (https://semver.org) because of which the list look like this when sorted:

```
 V1
 V10 
 V10.1 
 V10.2 
 V10.3 
 V10.3.1 
 V10.3.2 
 V10.4 
 V10.5 
 V10.6 
 V10.6.1 
 V10.6.2 
 V10.6.3 
 V10.6.4 
 V4 
 V5 
 V6 
 V7 
 V7.1 
 V7.2 
 V7.3 
 V8 
 V8.1 
 V8.2 
 V9 
 V9.1 
 V9.2 
 V9.3
```

I have thought about creating new columns and split on V and "." delimiter but my approach is lacking. In a new excel sheet (Data in N column) I have been trying to use
`=LEFT(N9;FIND("V";N9))` to get the "V"
`=RIGHT(N9;LEN(N9)-FIND(".";N9))` to get the second number. I am struggling to get the middle number(s) and also I doubt that this solution is even working for the versions with major, minor and patch number. How would I be able to sort the list by version? It should look like

```
V1
V4
V5
V6
V7
V7.1 
V7.2
V7.3
V8
V8.1
V8.2
V9
V9.1
V9.2
V9.3
V10
V10.1
V10.2
V10.3
V10.3.1
V10.3.2 
V10.4 
V10.5 
V10.6 
V10.6.1 
V10.6.2 
V10.6.3 
V10.6.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Formula

- Formula leverages the [`SORTBY`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sortby-function-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f) function using [`TEXTAFTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textafter-function-c8db2546-5b51-416a-9690-c7e6722e90b4) and [`TEXTBEFORE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textbefore-function-d099c28a-dba8-448e-ac6c-f086d0fa1b29) to identify the strings at each level (depth).
- Maximum depth is set in the formula -- see examples **Formula (Depth 3)** and **Formula (Depth 4)** -- but there is no real penalty for over-provisioning.
- Periods `.` are used to delimit levels and additional periods are added to avoid formula errors.
- the strings are coerced to numbers before sorting therefore zero values are added with the periods as NULL values won't be coerced to numbers.  **`V1`** becomes **`V1.0.0.`** when checking to a depth of 3.  Similarly **`V1.2.3`** would become **`V1.2.3.0.0.`**.

###### Formula (Depth 3)

Valid: `V1` ; `V1.2` ; `V1.2.3`

```
=LAMBDA(y, FILTER(y, y<>""))(
    LAMBDA(x, 
       SORTBY(x,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".", "."),"V")*1,1,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".0.", ".",2),".")*1,1,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".0.0.", ".",3),".",2)*1,1
         )
    )(A1:A10000)
 )
```

To increase the maximum depth simply add additional rows following the same pattern.

###### Formula (Depth 4)

Valid: `V1` ; `V1.2` ; `V1.2.3` ; `v1.2.3.4`

```
=LAMBDA(y, FILTER(y, y<>""))(
    LAMBDA(x,
       SORTBY(x,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".", "."),"V")*1,1,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".0.", ".",2),".")*1,1,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".0.0.", ".",3),".",2)*1,1,
         TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(x&".0.0.0.", ".",4),".",3)*1,1
         )
    )(A1:A10000)
 )
```

[image]

| Original | Sorted |
| --- | --- |
| V10.4 | V1 |
| V9.01 | V2 |
| V9.3 | V4 |
| V10.2 | V5 |
| V10.5 | V6 |
| V8.2 | V7.2 |
| V9.2 | V7.3 |
| V10.65.1 | V7.10 |
| V8 | V8 |
| V10.6.4 | V8.2 |
| V10.1 | V8.11 |
| V7.3 | V9.01 |
| V5 | V9.1 |
| V1 | V9.2 |
| V8.11 | V9.3 |
| V10 | V10 |
| V4 | V10.1 |
| V6 | V10.2 |
| V10.3 | V10.3 |
| V7.10 | V10.3.1 |
| V7.2 | V10.4 |
| V10.3.1 | V10.5 |
| V9.1 | V10.6.4 |
| V2 | V10.65.1 |

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by making use of `Text to columns`in excel by setting delimiter as `.` and the new columns generated thereby. Follow these steps to achieve the result you desire.

Firstly, take the Reference data in first column:

[image: Data]

Then select the data and go to `Data>>Text to Columns`, select `Delimited` and press Next. Then do this:

[image: Checked]
The delimiter here is `.`

Then click `Next` and press **Enter**.

The result:

[image: Result]

Now we've to make two helper columns in order to keep the letter `V` in one column and the succeeding numbers in the another column.

Select **Column B** and Right Click to insert an Empty column. Repeat the process to add another Column and you'll get something like this:

[image: Newly added Two empty columns]

Select **B1** cell and enter `=LEFT(A2, 1)`. Drag down to fill other cells in the column with letter **V**.

Now, select **C1** cell and enter `=RIGHT(A1, (LEN(A1)-SEARCH("V", A1, 1)))+0` and drag down to fill other cells. You will get a sheet like this:

[image: Filled sheet]

Now select the **Column C**, go to **Home** tab, click `Sort and Filter`, select `Smallest to Largest`, then expand the selection, and click **Sort**:

[image: Sorted]

You'll have a sheet as follows:

[image: Final sheet after sort]

Now, finally, select the **F1** cell and enter this formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(D1), CONCATENATE(B1, C1), IF(ISBLANK(E1), CONCATENATE(B1, C1, ".", D1), CONCATENATE(B1, C1, ".", D1, ".", E1)))`; Drag down to fill other cells and you'll obtain the desired result:

[image: Done and Dusted with this screenshot]

There you go. I hope it will be of help to you. I couldn't find any less-boring way to do this. Do let me know if this works for you :) Good night!